# Entry Category within channel:entries within options: loop within channel:form

Tags: channel-entries, categories, safecracker

I'm trying to display the channel entry category with `{categories}{category_name}{/categories}` but nothing shows up. I'm assuming that the `channel:form` somehow interferes with the `channel:entries` loop.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="message_on_hold" secure_return="yes" return="order/moh-checkout/ENTRY_ID" member_data="yes" error_handling="inline" secure_action="yes" entry_id="{segment_3}"}
  {options:moh_music}
    {if option_value != ''}

      <input type="radio" name="moh_music[data][]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>

      {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{option_value}" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
         {categories}{category_name}{/categories} ### Doesn't work, shows nothing
      {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/if}
  {/options:moh_music}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the channel you are linking to in the relationship field properly set up with a relivent category group (in Channel Preferences)?

Remember that within the `channel_entries` tag we are working on the child channel entries, not the parent!